# Isn't more comfortable to play Cmaj7 chord's root position 1245 instead of 1235 fingers on piano?

Tags: piano, harmony, jazz, fingering

As I saw in Youtube and in various websites that Cmaj7 root fingering should be 1235, but for me it would look like more logical to play 1245. Because when I play on RH 1235, my wrist goes to left. Did anybody thought in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably more dependant on where you're going next.
I naturally play it 1235 in isolation, but if I'm just passing through, then whichever leaves me a spare finger to make the next shift most easily. I'll play it 2345 if I've got a long jump to make with my thumb next, or 1234 if my next move is going higher.
My wrist doesn't really care which I do, the shift between 1235 & 1245 is very small. 1234 or 2345 is tougher, of course, but not impossible..

Comment: I see, but if you have to play this chord with RH at very low register, I think 1245 is better because you have to lean with your body less. Upper it doesn't matter whether you play 1235 or 1245.

Comment: It really doesn't bother my wrist wherever I play it. 1234 is a bit of a squeeze if it's really completely left of my body, but then I'd be leaning to compensate for that passage. Maybe it's just practice.

Comment: @vasik9888 - did you answer your own question in the comment?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one answer. If we were all clones, with identical physiology, there probably would be. But we're not and there isn't. How any website can be so self-assured to tell the world what's right, I'm not sure. But, it's on the 'net, so it must be true...

Play with whichever fingers you feel work best for you. It's you playing, it's your fingers, it's your decision. Sorry, but the bourgeoning number of experts out there are starting to get to me. One part of piano playing is actually working out what fingering works best. I'm still doing it with new stuff after 65 years - so it doesn't go away! But what I won't do is rely on someone else telling me what's best!

What precedes and comes after will have an impact on what fingering is used - for pretty well everything. So work through methodically, and use your own judgement, please!

This isn't so much a rant as reality! Imagine someone suggesting to Django Reinhart that he'd play better if he used his ring finger at that point?